# How to use void Subject in RxJava2?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, subject

I've managed to create it this way:

```
private final PublishSubject<Void> subject = PublishSubject.create();
```

But how to pass value to it in `onNext(T t)`? I can't pass null to it, cause it will throw an exception. `onComplete` isn't an option too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nulls are generally not allowed in 2.x thus a `Void` type won't let you emit any `onNext(null)` unlike 1.x. If you think you need `Void` as your element type, it indicates you don't care about what elements are just that you want to react to something over and over.

For this case, you can instead use any other type and signal any value. In the [wiki](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#nulls) there is an example you can adapt:

```
enum Irrelevant { INSTANCE; }

PublishSubject<Irrelevant > source = PublishSubject.create();

source.subscribe(e -> { /* Ignored. */ }, Throwable::printStackTrace);

source.onNext(Irrelevant.INSTANCE);
source.onNext(Irrelevant.INSTANCE);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just thought maybe there are some built-in class es in the framework, that I could use. I think it's a good idea to add this functionality to the framework.

Comment: We don't have built in types for anyone's business object, otherwise imagine you'd be constrained by our `RxUser` object not having a certain field or structure...

Answer (score 3):

In **Kotlin** you can use Unit:

```
val source = PublishSubject.create<Unit>()

source.onNext(Unit)
```

Comment: You can't pass null to `onNext`, it's better to use `Unit` type I guess - the equivalent of `void` in Java